# Bot FrameWork IE Issue using ReactJS and NodeJS web APP

Tags: node.js, reactjs, internet-explorer, botframework

Hi I have bot framework implementation using Nodejs and reactjs in azure web app. The code works perfectly fine in Edge, Chrome but IN IE, i get blank page with the error attached. Below is the code. In Fact even when i try one of the example microsoft has on github it fails to load in IE. [Here](https://microsoft.github.io/BotFramework-WebChat/03.a.host-with-react/) is the sample.

I did some reasearch and found out that reactjs does have some rendering issue with IE and that we should use polyfill package in our code, which i did still no luck.

```
import 'react-app-polyfill/ie11';
declare var require: any
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
import ReactWebChat, { createDirectLine } from 'botframework-webchat';
import { createStore } from 'botframework-webchat';
import { createStyleSet } from 'botframework-webchat';
import updateIn from 'simple-update-in';
import "babel-polyfill";
import "isomorphic-fetch";
//import 'react-app-polyfill/ie11';

export class BotFrameworkApp extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            directLine: null,
            styleSet: null,

        };
    }
        const response = await fetch('https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/tokens/generate', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer token',
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Access-Control-Request-Headers': 'x-requested-with'
            },

            body: JSON.stringify({
                accessLevel: 'View',
                allowSaveAs: 'false',
            })
        });
        const { token } = await response.json();
        //already set and now send

        this.setState(() => ({
            directLine: createDirectLine({ token }),
            userName: loginID,
            webchatStore: createStore({}, middleware),
            styleSet: createStyleSet({
                hideUploadButton: true,
                bubbleBackground: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, .1)',
                bubbleFromUserBackground: 'rgba(0, 255, 0, .1)',

            })
        }));



    }
    render() {
        const {
            state: { data }
        } = this

        return (
            this.state.directLine && this.state.webchatStore ?
                <ReactWebChat
                    className="chat"
                    directLine={this.state.directLine}
                    styleSet={this.state.styleSet}

                />
                :
                <div>Connecting to bot&hellip;</div>
        );
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(<BotFrameworkApp />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

This is the error,

[image]

[image]

My tsconfig

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "files": [
    "app.tsx"
  ]
}
```

My Webpack-config.js

```
module.exports = {
    devtool: 'source-map',
    entry: './app.tsx',
    mode: "development",
    output: {
        filename: "./app-bundle.js"
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.Webpack.js', '.web.js', '.ts', '.js', '.jsx', '.tsx']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'ts-loader'
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Which version of IE browser version are you using? As far as I know, the BotFramework support IE 11+. Besides, please explain more detail about the error message, and I suggest you could refer to this thread to add the react application polyfill and make it works well in IE browser.

Comment: Hi Thank you for u response.I am using IE 11.557.17763.0... can you please share the link to the thread for the polyfill.....

Comment: You could check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56435589/starter-create-react-app-with-ie11-polyfill-import-still-aborts-in-ie11/56439822#56439822) and [this article](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/tree/master/packages/react-app-polyfill).

Comment: Hi Zhi - i tried both the things still no luck with it.

Comment: Hi @mdrichardson-MSFT yes i was able to solve the issue, baed on ur suggestion. i did 'converting code from ES6+ to ES5 using polyfills and transpilers like babel'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Per the README](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat#browser-compatibility):

> Customization as shown in non-ES5 samples are not supported for Internet Explorer. Because IE11 is a non-modern browser, it does not support ES6, and many samples that use arrow functions and modern promises would need to be manually converted to ES5. If you are in need of heavy customization for your app, we strongly recommend developing your app for a modern browser like Google Chrome or Edge.
>
> Web Chat has no plan to support samples for IE11 (ES5).
>
> For customers who wish to manually rewrite our other samples to work in IE11, we recommend looking into converting code from ES6+ to ES5 using polyfills and transpilers like babel.

That being said, the README [sort of offers a workaround](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat#browser-compatibility) that I mostly got working. You'll have to play with CSS to finish it off.

**Create your app**

```sh
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm i
```

**Install additional modules**

```
npm i -S babel-polyfill react-app-polyfill/ie11 botframework-webchat
```

Note: Make sure you're using the latest version of `botframework-webchat`. The team is adding IE11 compatibility fixes pretty frequently.

**Add modules to project**

Put this at the **TOP** of your `index.js`:

```js
import 'babel-polyfill';
import 'react-app-polyfill/ie11';
```

**Ensure support of IE** (I'm guessing you're missing this part)

In `package.json`, make sure `browserlist` covers: `"ie 11"`.

Note: in the default `production` list, it has `">0.2%"`, which [covers IE11](https://browserl.ist/?q=%3E0.2%25)