# React Redux with SSR vs IE11 - The client app don't start

Tags: webpack, react-redux, internet-explorer-11, babeljs, server-side-rendering

We have built an App in React-Redux with SSR. It works wonderfully on every browsers except Internet Explorer 11 and bellow. The app is rendered on server side and display on client browser, but the app don't start. The page become a static page. Any navigation will reload the app.

We use Webpack and Babel to compile the code. The Babel preset-environment targets IE11. No error are displayed in the IE11 console.

webpack.config.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');
var MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const CompressionPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin');
var Visualizer = require('webpack-visualizer-plugin');

const pkgPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'package.json');
const pkg = fs.existsSync(pkgPath) ? require(pkgPath) : {};
let theme = {};

if (pkg.theme && typeof pkg.theme === 'string') {
  let cfgPath = pkg.theme;
  // relative path
  if (cfgPath.charAt(0) === '.') {
    cfgPath = path.resolve(__dirname, cfgPath);
  }
  const getThemeConfig = require(cfgPath);
  theme = getThemeConfig();
} else if (pkg.theme && typeof pkg.theme === 'object') {
  theme = pkg.theme;
}

module.exports = {
  mode: process.env.NODE_ENV,
  entry: { bundle: './src/client.js' },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: 'js/[name].js',
    chunkFilename: 'js/plugins/[name].js',
    publicPath: "/",
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: [/node_modules/],
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          query: {
            plugins: [
              "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
              "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
              "@babel/plugin-syntax-jsx",
              "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
              "@babel/plugin-transform-object-assign",
              "dynamic-import-webpack",
              ["import", { "libraryName": "antd" }],
            ],
            presets: [
              ["@babel/preset-env", {
                "targets": {
                  "edge": "17",
                  "firefox": "60",
                  "chrome": "67",
                  "safari": "11.1",
                  "opera": "55",
                  "ie": "11"
                }
              }],
              "@babel/preset-react"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          { loader: 'css-loader', options: { importLoaders: 1 } },
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              ident: 'postcss',
              plugins: (loader) => [
                require('autoprefixer')(),
                require('cssnano')()
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          'css-loader',
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              ident: 'postcss',
              plugins: (loader) => [
                require('cssnano')()
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            loader: 'less-loader',
            options: {
              modifyVars: theme,
              javascriptEnabled: true
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(svg|woff|woff2)$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'url-loader',
          query: {
            name: 'build/img/[name].[ext]',
            limit: 10000
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(eot|ttf)$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'file-loader',
          query: {
            name: 'build/img/[name].[ext]'
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'file-loader',
          query: {
            name: 'assets/[name].[ext]'
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },

  optimization: {
    minimizer: [new UglifyJsPlugin({
      uglifyOptions: {
        compress: {
          collapse_vars: false
        }
      }
    })],
  },

  plugins: [
    // Transmit Docker env variables to the browser, fallback to dev if not present
    // (in development, the build is run outside Docker)
    new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin({
      NODE_ENV: 'development',
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.local': JSON.stringify(true)
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: 'css/[name].css'
    }),
    new CompressionPlugin(),
    // load `moment/locale/en.js` and `moment/locale/fr.js`
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/moment[/\\]locale$/, /en|fr/),
    new Visualizer()
  ],

  // Automatically transform files with these extensions
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
    modules: ['node_modules']
  }
};
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "Project",
  "version": "1.3.3",
  "description": "client with Universal JavaScript",
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "rm -rf build && mkdir build",
    "build-server": "BABEL_ENV=node babel -d ./build ./src -s",
    "build-prod": "npm run clean && npm run build && npm run build-server && npm run transfer-file",
    "transfer-file": "babel ./src --out-dir ./build --copy-files",
    "e2e": "nightwatch",
    "start:universal": "npm run start",
    "start": "npm run build && BABEL_ENV=node babel-node src/server.js",
    "start:dev:universal": "npm run start:dev",
    "start:dev:docker": "([ -f \"build/js/bundle.js\" ] || npm run build:dev) && npm run start:dev",
    "start:local:docker": "([ -f \"build/js/bundle.js\" ] || npm run build:local) && npm run start:dev",
    "build": "webpack -p --config webpack.config.preprod.js --progress",
    "build:dev": "webpack -d --config webpack.config.dev.js",
    "start:dev": "BABEL_ENV=node nodemon --exec babel-node -- src/server.js",
    "build:dev:watch": "npm run clean && webpack -d --config webpack.config.dev.js --watch --progress",
    "build:local": "webpack -d --config webpack.config.local.js",
    "build:local:watch": "npm run clean && webpack -d --config webpack.config.local.js --watch --progress",
    "start:preprod:docker": "([ -f \"build/js/bundle.js\" ] || npm run build:preprod) && npm run start:preprod",
    "build:preprod": "webpack -d --config webpack.config.preprod.js",
    "start:preprod": "BABEL_ENV=node nodemon --exec babel-node -- src/server.js",
    "webpacker": "node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/.bin/webpack-cli --progress --color --config webpack.config.dev.js"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/genclik/fundky-client.git"
  },
  "author": "ODE Technologies",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.19",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.9.0",
    "@fortawesome/pro-light-svg-icons": "^5.9.0",
    "@fortawesome/pro-regular-svg-icons": "^5.9.0",
    "@fortawesome/pro-solid-svg-icons": "^5.9.0",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.4",
    "algoliasearch": "^3.33.0",
    "antd": "^3.22.0",
    "blueimp-load-image": "^2.24.0",
    "classnames": "^2.2.5",
    "compression": "^1.7.3",
    "credit-card-type": "^7.1.0",
    "deep-diff": "^1.0.2",
    "detect-browser": "^2.1.0",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "i18next": "^15.0.4",
    "i18next-express-middleware": "^1.7.1",
    "i18next-node-fs-backend": "^2.1.1",
    "instantsearch.css": "^7.3.1",
    "is-in-browser": "^1.1.3",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "json-markup": "^1.1.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "log4js": "^3.0.5",
    "log4js-node-sentry": "^1.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.19.3",
    "morgan": "^1.9.1",
    "normalize.css": "^8.0.1",
    "nuka-carousel": "^4.5.11",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "query-string": "^4.3.4",
    "react": "^16.8.2",
    "react-beautiful-dnd": "^11.0.4",
    "react-circular-progressbar": "^0.8.0",
    "react-collapse": "^4.0.3",
    "react-color": "^2.17.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.2",
    "react-draft-wysiwyg": "^1.13.2",
    "react-helmet": "^5.2.0",
    "react-html-parser": "^2.0.2",
    "react-i18next": "^4.1.2",
    "react-idle-timer": "^4.2.5",
    "react-image-crop": "^7.0.5",
    "react-input-mask": "^2.0.4",
    "react-instantsearch-dom": "^5.7.0",
    "react-loadable": "^5.5.0",
    "react-motion": "^0.5.2",
    "react-perfect-scrollbar": "^1.5.3",
    "react-quill": "^1.3.3",
    "react-redux": "^5.1.1",
    "react-remarkable": "^1.1.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.1.1",
    "react-router-last-location": "^1.1.0",
    "react-router-redux": "^4.0.8",
    "react-router-scroll-memory": "^1.0.4",
    "react-sizes": "^1.0.3",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-thunk": "2.2.0",
    "sanitize-html": "^1.20.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "universal-cookie": "^2.1.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.2.3",
    "@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
    "@babel/node": "^7.2.2",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.4.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-jsx": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-object-assign": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.2.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.3.1",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.5.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "babel-plugin-dynamic-import-webpack": "^1.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-import": "^1.11.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-imports": "^1.5.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-require-ignore": "^0.1.1",
    "chromedriver": "^2.46.0",
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^2.1.1",
    "cssnano": "^4.1.10",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.11",
    "less": "3.9.0",
    "less-loader": "^4.0.4",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.4.5",
    "nightwatch": "^1.0.19",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.10",
    "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.2",
    "url-loader": "^1.1.2",
    "webpack": "^4.29.6",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.0",
    "webpack-visualizer-plugin": "^0.1.11"
  }
}
```

server.js

```
//----- NODE MODULE ------//
import path from 'path';
import express from 'express';
import compression from 'compression';
import i18nMiddleware from 'i18next-express-middleware';
import morgan from 'morgan';

//----- REACT MODULE ------//
import React from 'react';
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';
import { StaticRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import fetchMap from './chore/fetchMap';
import { fetchData } from './parts/chore/ssrUtils';
import Helmet from 'react-helmet';

//------- PROJECT MODULE -----//
import i18n from './chore/i18n-server';
import * as cookieUtils from './parts/common/cookieUtils';
import { fetchPlatformByName, fetchPlatformContent } from './platform/platformActions';
import { fetchOrganizationById } from './organization/organizationActions';
import {
  connect,
  setSessionLanguage,
  fetchMemberRoles,
  fetchMemberPlatformRoles,
  fetchMemberPlatformPermissions,
} from './parts/session/sessionActions';
import { getLocale } from './parts/session/sessionSelectors';
import rootReducer from './chore/rootReducer';
import configureStore from './parts/chore/configureStore';
import App from './chore/App';
import { dom as faDom } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
import log4js from 'log4js';
const config = require(`./config/config.${process.env.NODE_ENV}.json`);

// logs4js configuration
log4js.configure(config.logger);

// Logger
const logger = log4js.getLogger('Client');
const sentryLogger = log4js.getLogger('Sentry');

console.log = logger.debug.bind(logger);
console.info = logger.trace.bind(logger);
console.success = logger.info.bind(logger);
console.warn = logger.warn.bind(logger);
console.error = logger.error.bind(logger);
console.fatal = sentryLogger.fatal.bind(sentryLogger);

// Process - Exception
process.on('uncaughtException', function(err) {
  console.fatal(err);

  // Close the process
  process.exit(1);
});

const app = express();
app.disable('x-powered-by');

// Set secure cookies
if (!process.env.local) {
  app.set('trust proxy', 1);
}

// use ejs templates
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

// Webpack bundles & assets
app.use(compression());
app.use(express.static('build'));
app.use(i18nMiddleware.handle(i18n));

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  app.use(morgan('dev'));
}

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  let markup = '';
  let preloadedState = null;
  let helmet = Helmet.renderStatic();
  let status = 200;
  const context = {
    actionCreators: []
  };
  let store;
  let locale;
  let i18nServer;

  if (!process.env.UNIVERSAL) {
    // NO SSR: return the page directly
    return res.status(status).render('index', { markup, preloadedState, helmet, locale, faDom });
  }

  // Begin SSR
  cookieUtils.init(req.headers.cookie);
  store = configureStore(rootReducer);

  // Global data fetching
  Promise.all([
    store.dispatch(connect())
  ])
  .then(() => {
    const state = store.getState();
    if(state.session.userTypeId === 2) {
      store.dispatch(fetchMemberRoles());
    }
    locale = getLocale(state, req.path);
    return store.dispatch(setSessionLanguage(locale));
  })
  .then(() => {
    return store.dispatch(fetchPlatformByName(req.headers.platform))
  })
  .then(() => {
    const state = store.getState();

    store.dispatch(fetchPlatformContent(state.platform.platform.id));

    if(state.session.userTypeId === 2) {
      store.dispatch(fetchMemberPlatformPermissions(state.platform.platform.id));
      store.dispatch(fetchMemberPlatformRoles(state.platform.platform.id));
    }
    // 1.5. Get organization data from id
    return store.dispatch(fetchOrganizationById(state.platform.platform.organizationId));
  })
  .then(() => {
    // 2. Route-specific data fetching
    return fetchData(req.path, fetchMap, store, req.query);
  })
  .then(() => {
    // 4. Rendering
    i18nServer = i18n.cloneInstance();
    locale = getLocale(store.getState(), req.path);
    i18nServer.changeLanguage(locale);

    // If sitemap is requested, pass xml as content type in headers
    if ( req.path.match(/(sitemap_index.xml|page-sitemap.xml|campaign-sitemap.xml)$/) ) {
      res.header( 'Content-Type', 'application/xml' );
    }

    const rootComponent = React.createElement(StaticRouter, { location: req.url, context },
      React.createElement(App, {i18n: i18nServer, store, locale})
    );
    markup = renderToString(rootComponent);
  })
  .then(() => {
    // 5. Response
    // context.url will contain the URL to redirect to if a <Redirect> was used
    if (context.url) {
      let url = context.url;
      if (context.url === `/en/login` || context.url === `/fr/connexion`) {
        url += `?from=${req.url}`
      }

      return res.redirect(302, url);
    }

    if (context.is404) {
      status = 404;
    }

    if ( req.path.match(/(sitemap_index.xml|page-sitemap.xml|campaign-sitemap.xml)$/) ) {
      // Use sitemap view
      res.status(status).render('sitemap', { markup });
    } else {
      preloadedState = JSON.stringify(store.getState());
      helmet = Helmet.renderStatic();
      res.status(status).render('index', { markup, preloadedState, helmet, locale, faDom });
    }
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log('===== ERROR SERVER =====');
    console.error(err);
    console.log('===== ERROR SERVER =====');

    markup = err;
    res.status(500).render('index', { markup, preloadedState, helmet, locale, faDom });
  });
});

app.options('*', (req,res) => res.status(405));

app.all('*', (req,res,next)=>{
    res.header('Accept-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Accept-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST,GET,DELETE,PUT,OPTIONS');
    res.header('Accept-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With,Accept,Origin');
    if(req.method=='OPTIONS'){
        res.sendStatus(200);
    }else {
        next();
    }
});

// start the server
const port = process.env.PORT || 5557;
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

app.listen(port, err => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err.stack);
  } else {
    console.info('==============================================================================');
    console.info(`Server listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
    console.info(`Universal rendering: ${process.env.UNIVERSAL ? 'enabled' : 'disabled'}`);
    console.info(`Env: ${env}`);
    console.info('==============================================================================');
  }
});
```

The application should work properly on Internet Explorer 11 as on other browsers.

Comment: Have you added right polyfills for IE 11? You could refer to [this thread](https://wildfly.org/downloads/) about how to make react app to support IE 11. As we have no idea about how you build your SSR react-redux app, we can't reproduce the issue. Could you please provide [a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can test it on our sides?

Comment: Thank you @YuZhou for your help. I added the server script in the post. I'm trying to find the best way to give you a minimal reproductive example, but it's a heavy project with PCI certification. I can't give too much information. 
PS: I don't think you give me the good link of the thread about how to make react app to support IE 11.

Comment: Sorry about the wrong link, it should be this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56435589/starter-create-react-app-with-ie11-polyfill-import-still-aborts-in-ie11/56439822#56439822