# IE loads with a blank page even when I added the react polyfill

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internet-explorer

I created my react app using `npx create-react-app my-app` but when I try to load the web application on IE11, it just prints a blank page.

I also added the polyfill by installing using the command `yarn add react-app-polyfill` and then including the following :

```
import 'react-app-polyfill/ie9';
import 'react-app-polyfill/ie11';
import 'react-app-polyfill/stable';
```

inside `src/index.tsx`. But still it loads the blank page. What should I do? I have no clue on how to proceed.

Comment: I suspect even without the polyfill that even a brand new, freshly initialized, created react app should render *something*. Any warnings/errors in the log? You ran `npm i` to install the dependencies, and you're running `npm start` to build and start the local dev server?

Comment: @DrewReese Yes I did that but just a blank screen without any console errors

Answer (score 0):

What is your `react-scripts` version? There're some issues with `react-scripts` version 3.3.0 and higher. You could find many issue reports in GitHub, for example: [github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8197](http://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8197), [github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8195](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8195).

It can still work with `react-scripts@3.2.0`. You could try to revert back to 3.2.0 as a workaround. Please also remember to [have polyfills for IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56435589/starter-create-react-app-with-ie11-polyfill-import-still-aborts-in-ie11/56439822#56439822), delete `.cache` folder in `node_modules` and delete IE browser cache then try again.