# IE11 Error: TypeError: non-array objects must have a [Symbol.iterator]() method

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer-11, polyfills

My application working fine on Firefox and Google Chrome, but unfortunately not on IE 11 or Edge.
I have installed `"react-app-polyfill": "^1.0.6"`, added all the polyfills needed as explained below:

index.js

```
import 'react-app-polyfill/ie11';
import 'react-app-polyfill/stable';
```

package.json

```
 "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version",
      "last 1 ie version"
    ]
  }
```

Error on IE11:

```
TypeError: Invalid attempt to iterate non-iterable instance.\nIn order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a [Symbol.iterator]() method.


_createForOfIteratorHelper
node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/createForOfIteratorHelper.js:54


> 54 |   throw new TypeError("Invalid attempt to iterate non-iterable instance.\\nIn order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a [Symbol.iterator]() method.");
     | ^
  55 | }
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Have you followed the steps in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56435589/starter-create-react-app-with-ie11-polyfill-import-still-aborts-in-ie11/56439822#56439822) to support IE 11 in react app? If the error still persists, please provide [a minimal, reproducible sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can have a test and see how to help. You could use some online code editor like StackBlitz or codesandbox. With only the above error message, we can't locate the issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm sharing with you the issue and the answer. As I have mentioned above, that I have added all the polyfills required but the issue still remains.

After couple of hours of debugging I have found out that `for` loop `of` format causing the issue, as it's not supported on IE11:

Old format:

```
for (const element of nameArray) {
  console.log(element);
}
```

New format:

```
for(const i = 0; i < nameArray.length; i++) {
  const str = nameArray[i];
}
```

Comment: This answer has helped me a lot also, thanks

Comment: This was the answer for Angular/TS with Ionic6 too.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `babel` polyfill to your app

```
npm install --save babel-polyfill
```

Add below line at top of `index.js` file

```
import "babel-polyfill";
```

For more information, check similar issue and solution details [here](https://medium.com/@kartal.erkoc/why-and-when-to-use-babel-polyfill-in-react-app-a-simple-example-8283f6ea68bb).

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still getting the same error on local dev, but when I build the application I get this error: SCRIPT5022: Exception thrown and not cought   export.js (var global = require ('../internals/global')). It's a file inside core-js