# IE11 polyfills don't work for React app. Why?

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, create-react-app, polyfills

In IE11 I get these errors:

[image]

But i have react-app-polyfill installed and imported in index.js first line:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, How about the issue? Is [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71221386/ie11-polyfills-dont-work-for-react-app-why/71233086#71233086) helpful to deal with the issue? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to add `ie 11` in **package.json** like this:

[image]

For more information, you can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56435589/starter-create-react-app-with-ie11-polyfill-import-still-aborts-in-ie11/56439822#56439822). I create a new React app according to [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#create-react-app) then do the steps in the answer I mention above, the React app can work well in IE 11.